# Safely using performSelector: with a method that returns an allocated object

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

If I'm using ARC, how can I call the following method using `performSelector:` without leaking?

```
- (SomeClass *)test {
    return [[SomeClass alloc] init];
}
```

If I use something like the following, I get a warning that I might introduce leaks, because ARC doesn't know what to do, since the selector is generated programmatically.

```
[object performSelector:selector];
```

Comment: That method doesn't actually leak. Because of the naming rules, the compiler will autorelease the returned object for you (under ARC).

Comment: @KevinBallard, even if the compiler can't tell what the selector name is?

Comment: Yes. The memory behavior of the function is defined by the function itself. The warning is telling you that ARC cannot tell if the return value of `-performSelector:` is a +1 or a +0 object. If you're calling a method that returns a non-owned object (a +0 object) then there is no leak. But if you're calling a method that returns an owned object (a +1 object), then the call to `-performSelector:` will leak.

Comment: Basically, since the compiler can't tell, it issues a warning and then proceeds with the assumption that it returns a +0 object. So if the actual method returns a +0 object, everything is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you're fine. The warning is telling you that the compiler cannot tell if `-performSelector:` is going to return a +0 or a +1 object, and the compiler will proceed with the assumption that it's a +0 object. So whether or not you leak depends on the actual method called. In this case, your method is `-test`, which according to the naming rules returns a +0 object. So calling this method with `-performSelector:` will not leak.

Comment: So I would only have problems if the method would be named `-initTest`, or if the method was static and called `+allocTest`?

Comment: @rid: Or `+newTest`, or `-copy` or `-mutableCopy`. Or if you used an attribute to annotate it as returning a retained object, e.g. `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))`. Assuming that's not the case, the method will return a +0 object.